# How to average uniques rows in a dataset?

Tags: r, dataset, average

I have a big dataset. There are 25,500 rows within two columns in the dataset. First Column is species name and the second column is altitude(m).
[It is part of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz5I8.png)

.
.

As you see, every species usually has multiple altitudes. So species names are repeated in several rows. I want to average altitudes for every species (unique species names) and get an output like the one below What should I do?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eYdL.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouping functions (tapply, by, aggregate) and the \*apply family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is and example of how you can do it in base r:

```
# Create a test df. you need to import your own dateset into r
df <- data.frame(Species=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c'),
                 ALT=c(5, 8, 14, 18, 5, 7, 7))



#find mean ALT by species
aggregate(df$ALT, list(df$Species), FUN=mean)

# Group.1    x
#1       a  6.5
#2       b 13.0
#3       c  6.0
```

Or dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(ALT), mean)

#  Species   ALT
#  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 a         6.5
#2 b        13  
#3 c         6
```